# Similar idioms for have a knack for something

Tags: idioms, synonyms

As the question stated, I've googled and returned empty handed. It would be great if u guys can share with me your knowledge on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Know the ropes' is a common idiom, but doesn't easily 'transitivise in the same way that 'have a knack _for_' / 'have the knack _of_' do.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Could we have more details, please? E.g: what's wrong with your original (and idiomatic) *have a knack for something*? What is the situation in which you'd like to use the new phrase? What connotations or imagery are you after with the idiom you're looking for?

Comment: As Lawrence has mentioned^, you need to furnish your questions with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the input, guys. There's nothing wrong with the original idiom, I just like a bit of variety for when I want to express that I have a talent for something.

Answer (score 2):

I think ***[shine at](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shine+at)*** comes close to what you are looking for:

> - be good at; "She shines at math"

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

If the idea you're trying to express is that a person does something very well without seeming to have to work very hard to be good at it, you might use the term **natural**, as in "Some people take years to learn a new language, but he's a **natural** at it."

Here is the entry for *natural* in the relevant group of closely related senses in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **natural** *n.* ... **4 a :** one having natural skills, talents, or abilities **b :** something that is likely to become an immediate success **c :** one that is obviously suitable for a specific purpose